# C# Description of a method signature

Tags: c#

Is there a .NET method that will produce a description of a C# method signature from a 
MethodInfo object.
E.g.
The following code might display "static int Main(string[])"

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var method = MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod();
    Console.WriteLine(DescribeMethodSignature(method));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a complete answer, but there is code generation functionality in the Framework. Check out the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx), specifically the [ICodeGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.icodegenerator.aspx) interface.

There is an [example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/dynacodgen.aspx) on how to use it.

Comment: To use CodeDom, you should manually build a syntax tree (good for more generic problem). For this simple problem, manually crafting the string is much easier.

Answer (score 1):

.NET base class library does not have such a method. This is C# specific and it doesn't make sense to have it in a class library shared among many languages. It shouldn't be hard to write one though.